# 1920x1080 Scrolling

Tags: resolution

This is about to drive me up the wall. After an update last week my Ubuntu 12.10 machine has a scrolling screen when I switch it to 1920x1080 (16:9). I can't seem to find anyone who has the same problem. Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Comment: Can you give us more information? what kind of graphics card do you have? Can you give your xorg.conf if it exists, and maybe the vga lines from lspci?

Comment: It is an Intel integrated chipset not a card. Not sure what kind though. Not sure where the configuration file is located. 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated Controller is what lspci is giving me.

Comment: That looks like an intel chipset to me. The file is in the folder /etc/X11.

Comment: Ya that is what it is. I am not seeing the config file.

Comment: Okay, it probably doesn't have an xorg.conf file then. Do you know what software was updated in the last update?

Comment: I have no clue. The only thing I can tell you is it required a restart and it was working perfectly before.

Comment: I'd try installing the updates from x-updates in my answer below. If it works for you, please accept my answer. If not, let me know if you get any change in output/errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try installing an updated version of X11 using either the xorg-updates, or the bleeding edge xorg-edgers PPAs:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates

https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

If those end up breaking your X11, the ppa-purge tool can be used to revert back to the normal repository.